# PayPal IPN: Reading multiple item_name and quantities and saving to a database

Tags: php, paypal

Below is my IPN code. My problem is that I am not able to add multiple item names or quantity in the table `payments_paypal`. In fact IPN is not listening payer_id,quantity,item_name(multiple items).

How can we $_POST item_name1 or item_name2 etc here, so that at the time of verify I can get it in other page that will be success page. Though I have achieved this by other method but that is not proper method. So I am wondering why these variables are not coming from ipn in the form of string only these variables are coming in string txn,smt,st,currency and the rest are all missing. If we have to use loop here how can we send values to insert in loop from here ipn.php.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data); 
    $myPost = array(); 
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) { 
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval); 
        if (count($keyval) == 2) 
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]); 

    }

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) { 
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true; 
    } 
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) { 
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
        } else { 
            $value = urlencode($value); 
        } 
        $req .= "&$key=$value"; 
    } 

    /* 
     * Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine 
     * Without this step anyone can fake IPN data 
     */ 
    $paypalURL = PAYPAL_URL; 
    $ch = curl_init($paypalURL); 
    if ($ch == FALSE) { 
        return FALSE; 
    } 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 

    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name')); 
    $res = curl_exec($ch); 

    /* 
     * Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly 
     * Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp 
     */  
    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res)); 
    $res = trim(end($tokens)); 
    if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { 

        // Retrieve transaction info from PayPal 
        $item_number    = $_POST['item_number']; 
        $txn_id         = $_POST['txn_id']; 
        $payment_gross     = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
        $currency_code     = $_POST['mc_currency']; 
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status']; 
         $quantity   = $_POST['quantity']; 

        // Check if transaction data exists with the same TXN ID 
        $prevPayment = $db->query("SELECT payment_id FROM payments WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'"); 
        if($prevPayment->num_rows > 0){ 
            exit(); 
        }else{ 
            // Insert transaction data into the database 
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO payments_paypal(item_number,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status) VALUES('".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')"); 
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the code you are using in the section `// Retrieve transaction info from PayPal` is extremely simple, and not written to look for multiple items, e.g. numbered variables like `item_name1`, `item_name2`, etc.

You should log the text of the IPNs you are receiving and not processing correctly, or obtain their text from your PayPal account history: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/where-can-i-access-my-ipn-history-faq3692

And also, review the documentation of the variable names for multiple items: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Then, you can modify your code to read and process those multiple numbered variables, and store them in whatever database schema you desire, which may need additional columns or whatever.